# how to select only some columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlalchemy

**This is my python code:**

```
 cx=sqlalchemy.create_engine(u"mysql://username:password@ipaddress/database?charset=utf8")

 metadata=sqlalchemy.MetaData(cx)
 orm_obj=sqlalchemy.Table(u'I_POI',metadata,autoload=True)


 sql=orm_obj.select(u'poi_id,poi_name').where(u'poi_id>1 and poi_id>0').limit(3).offset(0)

 resultz=sql.execute()
 for i in resultz:
     print i
```

---

[DB] I_POI Table:poi_id,poi_name,poi_data1,poi_data2......poi_data10

I do it with existing database,but "select()" is no work..It still return total columns.
I want to get only some columns,please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is the code that works for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_

results = select([orm_obj.c.poi_id, orm_obj.c.poi_name])\
    .where(and_(orm_obj.c.id > 1, orm_obj.c.id < 100)).execute()
for id, name in results:
    print id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use general purpose `select` instead of `Table.select`:

```
stmt = select([orm_obj.c.poi_id, orm_obj.c.poi_name]).\
where(and_(orm_obj.c.poi_id > 1, orm_obj.c.poi_id < 100)).\
limit(3)
result = conn.execute(stmt)
```